# IE alternative to window.stop() (cancel all pending requests)

Tags: asp.net, ajax, internet-explorer, request

I'm looking for an alternative to window.stop() for IE. I have tried document.execCommand('Stop'), but it doesn't seem to work. I'm trying to cancel a XMLHttpRequest which is called from within a ASP user control i'm using. I can't use jQuery's .abort() since i do not set the request my self.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume control on the page uses jQuery.ajax and you know when you need to abort the request, under your criteria.

How about something like this?

```
(function ($) {
    var xhr = null, 
        originalAjax = $.ajax,
        updatedAjax = function (url, options) {
            xhr = originalAjax(url, options);
        };
    $.ajax = updatedAjax;
})(jQuery);
```

Now you have a variable called xhr which  holds the underlying xmlhttp object. You can call abort() on the object when you need to.

The draw back is that variable will be populated for each ajax request done by jQuery, and I would only include this script on that particular page, maybe even reset the ajax when you are done.

I haven't tried this, just an idea, as I have been mocking ajax calls all the time. Some might think that this approach is a little bit drastic!

Hope you find it useful.

Comment: I like your approach. It is exactly what i want to do. I'm not that good with jQuery though, so i'm having some troubles. I'm not sure your sample code should run only once and after that the xhr variable should be automatically populated for each request, or i should run the code every time i want to caputre a request. If i run it once (just putting the code in the script block) i always have the same request with STATUS OK inside the xhr. If i put your code in the function where i whant to abort the current requests, xhr stays null. I would really appreciate your help. Thank you very much :)

Comment: That code should only run once on the page load, before any ajax request. You also need to be careful about scoping, you want the variable on a global scope, so you can get rid of the jquery scoping and put that in the ready event. Again, for each request, that variable will be loaded, and it will be overridden, so you need to grab that before it does. Hope you get it working, you are welcome! Don't forget to mark my answer if it does ;)

Comment: I need to abort the request only if the user wants to, so i need to have the current pending request inside a variable. What i do have inside xhr is an already completed request. How do i grab that last pending request? Thanks for bearing with me on this (:

Comment: OK, you should always have the last request in that variable, but don't forget that we are overriding the global $.ajax, so there might be other requests which may already replaced xhr variable's value. Do you know the endpoint that user control calls? If you do, you can check if the options.url is equal to your url, and only set the xhr object then. Makes sense?

Comment: Well it seems i made a big mistake on my part. What i see now is that i capture all ajax requests made with jQuery (your code works just fine), but it seems the request i'm trying to capture is not made using $.ajax. I'll try and research how is that request made. Never the less, you were most helpful. I'll definitely use your code solving other problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the object you can do it with the object's abort() and onreadystatechange event handler. Here is a working example I tweaked from [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/tryit.asp?filename=try_dom_xmlhttprequest_first)

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadXMLDoc()
{
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==2){ xmlhttp.abort();}
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","xmlhttp_info.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Using the XMLHttpRequest object</h2>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, the request text is not loaded because it gets aborted.

Answer (score 0):

I understand you don't set the request yourself, but do you have any kind of access to it, so that you can use the onreadystatechanged-event in javascript? If so, you can then determine whether or not you have to cancel the event.

Comment: I can't change the js code of the asp user control. If there is a way to capture the creation or firing of such request and then attach some sort of event to it, it would be great.