# Is it possible to stop images/resources from downloading without using window.stop()

Tags: javascript

I have tried using `window.stop()` to stop any currently loading images when a user closes a lightbox quickly after opening it.

It works perfectly and instantly stops all connections/images from downloading.  However it has the side-effect of stopping active websockets connections.

Is there any other way to stop images/resources from downloading without closing a websocket connection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9005822/ie-alternative-to-window-stop-cancel-all-pending-requests will answer your question.

Comment: Unfortunately not since these are not ajax requests but standard resource requests.  Therefore aborting the xhr object is not an option.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no way to stop the window from loading, but still load some things.

calling `window.stop()` is exactly the same as clicking the stop button in the browser, and it stops the loading of large images, new windows, and other objects whose loading is deferred, and that includes websockets, and any other scripts that where supposed to load, and you can't stop some things, and let other things load like the `stop()` function was never called. It's all or nothing really !

Comment: Thanks... Thats a shame I was really hoping there was something out there I was unaware of.  I suppose retriving the images via an XHR request and then using xhr.abort() would work but it feels like a bit of an ugly hack would require a substantial rewrite.  I guess I will just have to let this one go.  Thanks

Comment: When someone opens the lightbox, you could just programatically remove the `src` of the images, that will stop them from loading for sure, but if you intend to load them again later, you will have to keep track of what you removed, to add it back again. This is how many lazyload plugins do it.

Comment: does that actually abort the request though, or does it just prevent the onload event?

Comment: Just tested and it doesn't appear to abort the request in Firefox.  (setting img.src = '')

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have found a solution.  Although I don't really like it.  It involves creating a hidden iFrame within which you load the image.

Described in full here:

[Cancel single image request in html5 browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926215/cancel-single-image-request-in-html5-browsers)