# Prevent window.stop to block open websockets

Tags: javascript, websocket

I have a Websocket-based client-server communication protocol, which must be cross-browser compatible.

To prevent some MJPEG streams from running indefinitely on Safari and Chrome as described [in this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=73395), I launch a window.stop() javascript event under certain conditions.

On Chrome this keeps the websocket connection open, which is good.
On Firefox, however, the websocket is abruptly closed.

Is there a way to force some sockets to stay open with the window.stop() event?
The only workaround, otherwise, would be to use some browser sniffing ([bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661213/why-is-browser-sniffing-not-a-recommended-practice)) or to hope that Chrome devs will finally debug the MJPEG issue (which is unlikely).

Comment: It maybe of limited use to you, but see also: [Is it possible to stop images/resources from downloading without using window.stop()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16550295/is-it-possible-to-stop-images-resources-from-downloading-without-using-window-st)

Comment: Thanks, but looking the answer it seems that the only way involves iframes, which is not recommended in our case. We'd rather go through browser sniffing, so much for feature detection...